Composition @Repeatable annotations in custom annotation
For integration tests on Spring Boot, I need to combine 2 @Sql annotations into a custom one and transfer only the path to the scripts folder to one of them.
You can pass both paths, but the second one will probably be the same.
I wanted to know if it could be done in a more or less painless way?
As I understand it, the @AliasFor annotation will not be able to cover such a case where we have 2 identical annotations and their attributes match.
Is there any reliable and elegant solution for such a case?
NOTE: the value for insert will always be different
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "") // I need to pass the value in scripts
@Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "/constant_path")
public @interface SqlInsertAndClear {

    String[] insertScript() default {};
}

I'm trying to convey the meaning, but at the moment I don't understand how to do it better.
@AliasFor, as far as I understand, cannot cover a case where we have 2 identical annotations.
@AliasFor(annotation = Sql.class, attribute = "scripts") // Not working
String[] insertScript() default {};

